# Evaluating a volume integral $\iiint_ T (x+y-z)\,dV$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Like the limits of my integration are which?
$$\iiint_T  \left(x+y-z\right)\,dV \quad\quad T=\left\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \,|\, x^2+2y^2\leq z\leq3-2x^2-y^2  \right\}$$

Comment: Hint: you may want to change coordinate systems.

Comment: That may work, but I'm not sure if cylindrical or spherical coordinates can be applied here.

Comment: Spherical would be horrendously terrible, but cylindrical is OK. Note that the two surfaces intersect when $x^2+y^2=1$.

Comment: Notice that the integrand can be split into three parts, and $x$ and $y$ are odd functions in a region with $x,y\leftrightarrow-x,-y$

Comment: Per symmetry $$\iiint_T  \left(x+y-z\right)\,dV= \iiint_T  \left(-z\right)\,dV\\=-3\iint_{x^2+y^2<1}(1-x^2-y^2)dxdy=-\frac{3\pi}2
$$

Comment: Interesting. I typed the first integral into my calculator and I got $-\dfrac{9\pi}{4}$

Comment: I was trying to do without symmetry and have arrived in integrate $$
\int_{0}^{3}xdx\int_{1}^{-1}ydx\int_{1}^{x+y^2}-zdz $$, i suppose is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
[image]

Here is the region.

We transform this into cylindrical coordinates. The $z$ bound would just be the top and bottom functions, which are $x^2+2y^2$ and $3-2x^2-y^2$.

[image]

Removing the zed axis, the "shadow" of the region of integration seems to be a circle. Hence, the $r$ bound would be from $0$ to $1$, and theta going from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Thus, the integral is $$\iiint_T   x+y-z \text{ d}V = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_{r^2(\sin^2(\theta)+1)}^{3-r^2(\cos^2(\theta)+1)} (r\cos(\theta)+r\sin(\theta) - z)\cdot r \text{ d}z\text{ d}r\text{ d}\theta$$
$$\implies \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 -\frac32 r(r^2-1)(r^2\cos(2\theta)+2r\sin(\theta)+2r\cos(\theta)-3) \text{ d}r\text{ d}\theta$$
$$\implies \int_0^{2\pi} \frac1{40}(16\sin(\theta)+16\cos(\theta)+5\cos(2\theta)-45) \text{ d}\theta = -\frac{9\pi}4$$

This seems to be what @cpiegore got in the comments. Although I'm pretty confident in my answer, I'm not sure what Quanto did in the comments (and since he is pretty reputable, there's a chance my value is wrong), so verify my work here.

Comment: Nice answer. I’m not sure what @Quanto did either. Looks like he tried to integrate with respect to $z$ first and forgot that the integrand $-z$ is not a constant with respect to $z$. When you integrate $-z$ with respect to $z$ from $x^2+2y^2$ to $3-2x^2-y^2$, you get something much more complicated and horrible than $1-x^2-y^2$.

Comment: You are right. I was careless.

Comment: Thank you all, makes sense

Comment: @123 glad to help!